# Check mandatory argument of parameters

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, arguments, parameter

I have script with several parameters that have required argument:

```
while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
    case $1 in
        -f | --first )          shift
                                first=$1
                                ;;
        -s | --second )         shift
                                second=$1
                                ;;
        * )                     break
    esac
    shift
done

echo "first: "$first" second: "$second
```

This works properly:

```
$ ./script.sh --first a --second b
first: a second: b
```

But when someone forget about argument of parameter then getting parameters works incorrectly.

For example this not works:

```
$ ./script.sh --first --second a
first: --second second:
```

and this was bad (first was get, but second mandatory not handled):

```
$ ./script.sh --first a --second
first: a second:
```

---

I try modyify:

```
* )                     break
```

to:

```
* )                     echo "Bad arguments"
                        exit 1
```

In this case works (handling mandatory first):

```
$./script.sh --first --second b
Bad arguments
```

But in this case doesn't works properly (not handling second):

```
$ ./script.sh --first a --second
first: a second:
```

Comment: If the number of required arguments is always the same you could test for number of parameters given with `$#`, e.g. `if [ "$#" -ne 4 ]; then ...`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the shell built-in `getopts`.  This uses an optstring where you can list all of the valid option characters AND whether they require an argument or not (by following the option character with a `:`).  For example:

```
while getopts 'f:s:' opt; do
  case "$opt" in 
    f) first="$OPTARG" ;;
    s) second="$OPTARG" ;;

    :) usage 1 "-$OPTARG requires an argument" ;;
    ?) usage 1 "Unknown option '$opt'" ;;
  esac
done

shift $((OPTIND -1))
```

Note that the built-in `getopts` does not support --long options.  If that is a requirement, use the `getopt` program from the `util-linux` package - do NOT use any other version, the others all have serious flaws.

```
TEMP=$(getopt -o 'f:s:' --long 'first:,second:' -n "$0" -- "$@")
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo "Terminating..." >&2 ; exit 1 ; fi
eval set -- "$TEMP"

while true ; do
  case "$1" in
    -f|--first)    first="$2" ; shift 2 ;;
    -s|--second)   second="$2" ; shift 2 ;;
    --)            shift ; break ;; 
     *)            echo 'Internal error!' ; exit 1 ;;
  esac
done
```

---

NOTES:

- `getopts` (with an `s`) is built-in to POSIX shells and is portable and standard.
- `getopt` (without an `s`) is non-standard, with several conflicting versions, most of which have serious flaws.  The version from the `util-linux` package is safe to use if you don't care about portability.
- both of them will throw an error if an option that requires an argument is not given one.

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because `shift` does shifting of `$2` to `$1`  irrespective of what the text you have for cases. Exact purpose of your scripting is unclear but for instance if you want to avoid this, you can do something like:

```
while [[ "$1" != "" && "$2" != -* ]]; do
    case $1 in
        -f | --first )          shift
                                first=$1
                                ;;
        -s | --second )         shift
                                second=$1
                                ;;
        * )                     break
    esac
    shift
done

echo "first: "$first" second: "$second
```

This will avoid manipulation if argument is missing.

Example output:

```
$ ./script.sh --first a --second b
first: a second: b
$ ./script.sh --first --second b
first:  second:
```